# What is the equivalent of a hosts file mapping for AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, hosts

Our AppEngine app is connecting to a remote service which requires a VPN and also required me to add entries to the hosts file on my local machine in order to connect to their endpoints.
e.g.

10.200.30.150 foo.bar.com

This is working fine when running the app locally, but I can't figure out how to set this up on Google Cloud to work once deployed.
I can't use the IP addresses directly because it errors that the IP is not on the cert's list.

How do I map the host names to the IPs in Google Cloud so that AppEngine can use them?

Comment: Could you add some details about what have you tried that far and/or the error messages you got (either from deployment, connection , SSL). I also would like to know if is App Engine Standard or Flexible.

Comment: I have the VPN connection made using Cloud VPN with a vpn tunnel that's showing it's up and running. I've looked through much of the documentation on routing, but the use cases listed there don't seem to match what I'm looking for, and most of it seems focused on connecting within the VPC, or connecting to a local intranet. We're connecting to a 3rd party service which requires the VPN and the hosts mapping, so we don't have any control over that. 
I've tried connecting to the IP directly, but it's erroring: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP is not in the cert's list

Comment: And it looks like we're using App Engine Flexible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error mentioned in the comment I suspect connecting directly through the IP fails because the certificate doesn't recognize the IP to DNS mapping as valid and therefore the secure connection setup breaks. Based on the requirements of connecting to the API by VPN and tweaking the hosts mapping there are few things you may try.

The simplest approach that may work would be using a Google Compute Engine VM instance, since there you would able to manipulate the `etc/hosts` file and replicate the local machine setup. This VM could be used either as the main app  service or as a proxy from App Engine to the 3rd party API endpoint. To go that route I would suggest taking a look at these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762778/google-cloud-compute-engine-etc-hosts) [posts](https://serverfault.com/questions/766147/how-to-update-hosts-file-on-google-cloud-vm) which explain how to change the `etc/hosts` file on GCE (Changing the file once wouldn't work as the VM periodically overrides it, see the posts for cronjob like workaround).

Separately, as your app runs in App Engine flexible environment there is the chance to provide a [docker](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) container with the app packaged. It may be possible to set the workaround above in the docker file and have it working in App Engine too.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get a docker image to work, but it's turning out to be a lot of work... I'll accept as soon as I get it working :)

Comment: OK, finally got this working. For anyone else looking at this, I created a docker image based on one of Google's google apps images, then ran a startup script which updated the /etc/hosts file with the entries I needed.